# PDF uploading malicious content vulnerability with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, pdf, file-upload, carrierwave

I am implementing pdf upload using Carrierwave with Rails 4. I was asked by the client about malicious content, e.g. if someone attempts to upload a malicious file masked as a pdf. I will be restricting filetype on the frontend to 'application/pdf'. Is there anything else I need to worry about, assuming the uploaded file has a .pdf extension?

Answer (score 3):

File uploads is often a security issue, since there are so many ways to get it wrong. Regarding just the issue of masking a malicious file as a PDF, checking the content type (`application/pdf`) is good, but not enough, since it's controlled by the client and can be modified.

- Filtering on the `.pdf` extension is definitely advisable, but make sure you don't accept files like `virus.pdf.exe`.
- Other filename attack techniques exist, e.g. involving null or control characters.
- Consider using a file type detector to determine that the file is really a PDF document.

But that's just for restricting the file type. There are many other issues you need to be aware of when accepting file uploads.

- PDF files can contain malicious code and are a common attack vector.
- Make sure uploaded files are written to an appropriate directory on the server. If they aren't meant to be publicly accessible, choose a directory outside of the web root.
- Restrict the maximum upload file size.

This is not a complete list by any means. Check out the [Unrestricted File Upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) vulnerability by OWASP for more info.

Answer (score 1):

**In addition** to @StefanOS 's great answer, PDF files are required to start with the string:

```
  %PDF-[VERSION]
```

Generally, at least often, the first couple of bytes (or more) indicate the file type - especially for executables (i.e., Windows executables, called PE files, should start - if memory serves - with "`MZ`").

For uploaded PDF files, opening the uploaded file and reading the first 5 bytes should always yield `%PDF-`.

This might be a good enough verification. for most use-cases.